# maven hudson doc to pdf

Tags: pdf, maven-2, hudson, maven-pdf-plugin

My application has a bunch of document files (currently in word doc format) that I convert to PDF before distributing the application. Currently I manually convert them to PDF. This leaves me open to the chance that I could update the word document and forget to update the PDF (I can write a script to check that the PDF is newer than the doc, so that's some protection, but no guarantees)

Are there any plugins for either maven or hudson that will allow me to do this on the fly as part of the build? I couldn't seem to find one. I'd prefer it be in the maven side of things so it's tied to the software build, but I'd settle for a hudson plugin if needed.

thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried it, but there exists a project called [**JODConverter**](http://www.artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter), which does document conversions (including Word to PDF) using an OpenOffice instance running in headless server mode. It comes with a [Maven plugin](http://www.artofsolving.com/node/36).

Answer (score 0):

I have no knowledge of Maven, but if it allows you to call a web service then try looking at a product like the PDF Converter Services. [It comes with Java Based Sample code](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/04/convert-office-files-to-pdf-format-from.html).

I worked on this product so the usual disclaimers apply.